# Remove 'Del' linkfrom Action list view in product list under Oppportunities

Tags: profile, opportunity-lineitem

I would like to remove the 'Del' link which appears against every product in the Products( Standard Price Book) section under the Opportunities.

Is there any way to control it using profiles and users permissions, so that users will not be able to see this link except the System Administrator?

Regards,
SF User

Comment: Did you try removing delete permission for all the profiles except Sys Admin?

Comment: Hi, I have tried removing all the Delete permissions from other profiles but it works only for the 'Delete button' on Opportunity and Opportunity Products but not for the 'Del' link against the Product List.

Comment: If you remove delete access for opportunity products, users can't change the products once first added to the opp, and would need a sys admin to change the products on a deal for them or create a new opp while working on opps.  Does that fit your business process?